# How do I merge and delete duplicated rows in SQL using UPDATE for SQL server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, update, delete

For example, I have a table of:

```
id | code | name | type | deviceType
---+------+------+------+-----------
1  | 23   | xyz  | 0    | web
2  | 23   | xyz  | 0    | mobile
3  | 24   | xyzc | 0    | web
4  | 25   | xyzc | 0    | web
```

I want the result to be:

```
id | code | name | type | deviceType
---+------+------+------+-----------
1  | 23   | xyz  | 0    | web&mobile
2  | 24   | xyzc | 0    | web
3  | 25   | xyzc | 0    | web
```

How do I do this in SQL Server using `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements?

Note: Unfortunately I can't use the solutions given because SQL server 2014 does not have 'STRING_AGG' function.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

please, try this:

```
with stable as (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [code]) as [ID]
    , [code]
    , [name]
    , [type]
    , CASE
        WHEN (SUM([web]) = 1 AND SUM([mobile]) = 1) THEN 'web&mobile'
        WHEN (SUM([web]) = 1 ) THEN 'web'
        WHEN (SUM([mobile]) = 1) THEN 'mobile'
        ELSE null END AS deviceType
FROM (
    select [id], [code], [name], [type], [web], [mobile]
    from (
        SELECT [id], [code], [name], [type], [deviceType] FROM [dbo].[table]
    ) as source
    pivot 
    (
        COUNT(deviceType) FOR deviceType IN ([web],[mobile])
    ) as tb
) source
group by [code], [name], [type])
,ttable as (
SELECT [id], [code], [name], [type], [deviceType] FROM [dbo].[table]
)
MERGE
    INTO ttable as T
    USING stable as S
    ON t.id = S.id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            T.[code] = S.[code], T.[name] = S.[name], T.[type] = S.[type], T.[deviceType] = S.[deviceType]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE 
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to group by `code`, `name`, and `type` fields and get the aggregation of `deviceType`'s, in SQL Server 2014 you can use this workaround of `stuff` and `FOR XML`.  This is generic and will work with any values in the `deviceType` field.

One difference in this solution compared to your example output is the original rows/id's in the table get updated and extra ones removed.  In your example, id 1 and 2 are combined, so the final result keeps row 1 which is now 1 and 2, and removes id 2 as a separate row.

Here's a fully reproducible example verified in SQL Server 2014:

```
create table #tmp (
    id int not null,
    code int not null,
    name nvarchar(255) not null,
    type int not null,
    deviceType nvarchar(255) not null)

insert into #tmp values (1, 23, 'xyz', 0, 'web')
insert into #tmp values (2, 23, 'xyz', 0, 'mobile')
insert into #tmp values (3, 24, 'xyzc', 0, 'web')
insert into #tmp values (4, 25, 'xyzc', 0, 'web')

-- Original table for comparison
select * from #tmp

-- Output grouped by code, name, type, and aggregate deviceType
;with results as (
    select
    min(id) as id,
    code, 
    name, 
    type,
    ( 
        stuff((SELECT '&' + Cast(dt.deviceType AS VARCHAR (300)) [text()]
            FROM   #tmp dt
            WHERE  tmp.code = dt.code
                and tmp.name = dt.name
                and tmp.type = dt.type
            FOR xml path(''),
            type).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    ) as [deviceType]
    from #tmp tmp
    group by code, name, type
)
merge into #tmp
using results on #tmp.id = results.id
when matched then
    update set #tmp.deviceType = results.deviceType
when not matched by source then
    delete;

select * from #tmp

drop table #tmp
```